# Android app, magically cached font

Tags: android, fonts

I load the font in `onCreate()`:

```
Typeface arcadeFont;
arcadeFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/arcadefont.ttf");
```

next: `paint.setTypeFace(arcadeFont);`

It shows when I open it on an Android Emulator, but when I run the app on phone, it still loads the old font (not the default one, the one I uploaded earlier).

I have deleted the old font, reinstalled app, cleared app-cache - it still loads a font that doesn't exist.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you apply the typeface any where?

Comment: textPaint.setTypeface(arcadeFont);

in onDraw()

Comment: do it before onDraw in constructor. but it should work.